# Android Media Player randomly raises error and doesn't play

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-mediaplayer

I am making an instrument playing app ("Walkband" style) on Xamarin.Android for VS2017. 
I have an array of `MediaPlayers` called `players`.

This is the Play function, where `resid` is equivalent to `Resource.Raw.filename`:

```
public void Play(int resid)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!players[i].IsPlaying)
            {
                players[i].Reset();
                players[i] = MediaPlayer.Create(this, resid);
                players[i].Start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Most of the time it plays great, but occasionally (specifically after playing many resources in quick succession), it fails to play.

The log looks like this when it succeeds:

```
06-04 14:52:26.112 I/MediaPlayer(17611): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-04 14:52:26.112 I/MediaPlayer(17611): playback complete
```

And like this when it fails:

```
06-04 14:52:25.933 I/MediaPlayer(17611): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-19
06-04 14:52:25.933 E/MediaPlayer(17611): error (1, -19)
06-04 14:52:25.933 E/MediaPlayer(17611): Error (1,-19)
```

The resource itself isn't the issue, as all the resources mostly work, and all occasionally fail

Comment: Hi, does my answer work for you?

Comment: Use `MediaPlayer`, you can exhaust the available resources on the device, even if you properly release all the players (which I don't see in your code). If the clips you are playing are short, then Joe's answer is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an array of MediaPlayers called players.

You need to use [soundpool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069955/play-sound-using-soundpool-example), and please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287182/maximum-number-of-mediaplayer-variables).

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed!